# iOS UI testing for XMPP based app

Tags: ios, swift, testing, xmpp, xmppframework

I have XMPP based app that is something like chat. I use [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) for XMPP implementation. I would like to make UI testing where I need to send messages from different users. So I need to have mocking or two instances of app at the same time.

Is there framework for mocking or stubbing xmpp server like [OHTTPStubs](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs)?

Is there a way to run tests simultaneously with ability to specify which test methods should be run?

I tried to use [Bluepill](https://github.com/linkedin/bluepill) for it but it seems that it doesn't fit for my purpose.

Comment: That sounds like you want to test the implementation of XMPPFramework, your dependency. An easier path would be to mock that dependency and ensure that your app is calling the right methods.

Comment: Is there a simple way to have mocked XMPPFramework? Or it requires writing own mock implementation?

Comment: No, there's no mocked framework that you can just drop in. However, you only need to mock the exact methods that you call into, not the entire framework. Of course, it depends on how much of the framework you're using.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comments!